# Intermediate Linear Algebra Text

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have been struggling to find an intermediate-level linear algebra textbook.

I have tried Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra and found it convoluted. Additionally, some of the books like Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right seem a bit too theoretical for me (as I am not a math major). I want to strike a balance between theory and applications. I mainly want to gain some intuition behind the subject.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you think geometrically? What sorts of applications are you ultimately interested in?

Comment: [Lay's text](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-5th/dp/032198238X) is a popular choice

Comment: @BenGrossmann Lay's book does look appealing. Is it too elementary though?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I do. Any application that provides insight into LA.

Comment: @blacknapkins7 Depends on what you mean by "elementary" or "intermediate level". My instinct is that if you are having trouble parsing Strang's text and looking for something with the same mix of application and theory, then Lay's text is a good way to go. Lay's text is commonly used for introductory courses, but it contains material that is often skipped for the purposes of carving out that introductory course.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I will try it out. I merely found Strang's book to be somewhat incoherently formatted though it isn't the worst by any stretch.

Comment: @blacknapkins7 "Incoherently formatted" is an interesting criticism, I'd be interested to hear a bit more if you could elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I found the formatting convoluted. The digressions seemed useful but the organization lacked, IMO.